# Disc burning software of Ubuntu

Tags: brasero

I want to compile and write Xvid movie files to a disc for playing them on a standalone DVD player which requires ISO 9660 file system. How can I choose this file system with  the Brasero disc burner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look on k3b

```
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

When you start burning click on filesystem tab

[image]

By default this will support ISO 9660 file system but yo can configure more by clicking the custom button

[image]

Comment: I want to know whether that's possible with Brasero.

Comment: This is not possible with Brasero